# How to access objects in EL expression language ${}

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

If I have a

```
ArrayList<Person> persons
```

How do I access it in EL?

```
<c:foreach items="${what goes here??}" var="person">${person.title}</c:foreach>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The expression `${foo}` uses behind the scenes [`JspContext#findAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute-java.lang.String-) which searches for attributes in [`PageContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html), [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html), [`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) and [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) in this order by their `getAttribute("foo")` method whereby `foo` from `${foo}` thus represents the attribute name `"foo"` and returns the **first non-null object**.

So, if you do in a servlet

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = getItSomehow();
request.setAttribute("persons", persons); // It's now available by ${persons}
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/persons.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

And call this servlet by URL, then you'll be able to iterate over it in `page.jsp` as follows:

```
<c:foreach items="${persons}" var="person">
    ${person.title}
<c:forEach>
```

The above is also equally valid when you put it in the session scope instead

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("persons", persons);
```

or even in the application scope

```
getServletContext().setAttribute("persons", persons);
```

EL will for `title` in `${person.title}` implicitly look for a public instance (not static!) method prefixed with `get` in `Person` class like below:

```
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
```

The field `title` does not necessarily need to exist in the class (so you can even return a hardcoded string and keep using `${person.title}`), and it does not necessarily need to be an instance field (so it can also be a static field, as long as the getter method itself isn't static).

Only `boolean` (not `Boolean`!) getters have a special treatment; EL will implicitly look for a public method prefixed with `is`. E.g. for a `${person.awesome}`:

```
public boolean isAwesome() {
    return awesome;
}
```

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-shared-variables-and-multithreading)
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/)
- [Show JDBC ResultSet in HTML in JSP page using MVC and DAO pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003142/show-jdbc-resultset-in-html-table-in-jsp-page-using-mvc-pattern)
- [Use EL ${XY} directly in scriptlet <% XY %>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007689/use-el-xy-directly-in-scriptlet-xy/)
- [How does Java expression language resolve boolean attributes? (in JSF 1.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236929/how-does-java-expression-language-resolve-boolean-attributes-in-jsf-1-2/)

Comment: Thank you, especially the behind the scenes information as that really really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${names}"> ${item.title}  </c:forEach>
```

`names` should be in the set as attribute available for the view

Comment: when you say "set" are you refering to <c:set>?

Comment: you can set it in no. of ways. but it should be available to that page

Comment: Note that the syntax is wrong. You seem to have copypasted from Ashish.

Comment: @BalusC agree about syntax. and did you check time log about copying stuff :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't expect that you was the first who made the mistake :) (it is still incorrect though)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Servlets or action class for creating your list and then forwarding it to your JSP, then you must be having following line in your servlet or action class.

```
ArrayList<Person> names = "get from somewhere";

request.setAttribute("personNames",names);  

<c:foreach var="item" items="${personNames}"> ${item.title} </c:foreach>
```

Comment: If I were to put this in the session would it be any different?

Comment: @robertlewis2001 You will have to fetch the list from the session Scope from instead of the request scope.  It should become items="{sessionScope.personNames}".

Comment: Note that the syntax is wrong. As to the last comment, it's not necessary to explicitly mention the scope.