# Does EL automatically convert/cast the type? How does ${a.name} actually work?

Tags: jsp, javabeans, el, evaluation

I have a variable declared as type `Object a` which actually refers an instance of type `A`.

In EL, I can directly use the following expression to print the `name` property of type `A`:

```
${a.name}
```

How does it work?

Comment: It's not JSTL, it's Expression Language(EL).......

Comment: Indeed, I removed the JSTL tag and fixed the terminology in the question. To learn what JSTL is check http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info and to learn what EL is check http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info.

Answer (score 4):

EL uses [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) under the hoods, usually via [`javax.beans.Introspector` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html).

This is what it roughly does under the covers on `${a.name}`.

```
// EL will breakdown the expression.
String base = "a";
String property = "name";

// Then EL will find the object and getter and invoke it.
Object object = pageContext.findAttribute(base);
String getter = "get" + property.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + property.substring(1);
Method method = object.getClass().getMethod(getter, new Class[0]);
Object result = method.invoke(object);

// Now EL will print it (only when not null).
out.println(result);
```

It does not convert/cast the type in any way.

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [How to access objects in EL expression language ${}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387174/how-to-access-objects-in-el-expression-language)
- [Travesring through an object in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327411/travesring-through-an-object-in-java/)

Answer (score 3):

It's because `name` is a property of the object `a`, and probably the object is also a JavaBean (not to be confused with Enterprise JavaBean).

See [here](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) for Expression Language Documentation and [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=551) for a short tutorial.

Comment: a is currently type Object, but it is actually type A.

Comment: @user705414: How is this `a` instance being set? Could you provide some code examples?