# Why does <jsp:getProperty> need <jsp:useBean>, but EL doesn't?

Tags: jsp, servlets, javabeans, el

I have *servlet* with following code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Person p = new Person("Mike");
    req.setAttribute("person", p);

    RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp");
    view.forward(req, resp);
}
```

I have two choices for printing person's name inside *result.jsp*. Using `<jsp:getProperty>` or `Expression language`.

Simple **EL** code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html><body>

Welcome ${person.name}

</body></html>
```

Or using **jsp:getProperty** like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html><body>

<jsp:useBean id="person" type="com.example.Person" class="com.example.Person" scope="request"/>
Welcome <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name"/>

</body></html>
```

From my understanding, both these codes for getting name either by `${person.name}` or `<jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name"/>` call `findAttribute()`. But there is one major difference. Code written in EL doesn't need `<jsp:useBean>`, while `<jsp:getProperty>` works only combined with `<jsp:useBean>`.

We might ask how does `${person.name}` know what type of object is "person". Well, it uses something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498603/does-el-automatically-convert-cast-the-type-how-does-a-name-actually-work). My question is how can't `<jsp:getProperty>` work the same way as EL as stated in given link? Why can't it call *getClass()*,*getMethod()* and "spare" us struggle of typing **class**,**type**,**id**
inside `<jsp:useBean>`? Is it simply because EL is **newer**, thus providing us with less code needed to type, or there is something else hiding behind this that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the answers from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65524361/why-i-cant-use-jspgetproperty-without-jspusebean/) of yours, `<jsp:getProperty>` uses `<jsp:useBean>` because the JSP specification says so. Why it was decided to work like that is a question best asked to those that drafted the spec. Finding out exactly the reason might satisfy your curiosity :) but it won't make any change in the way the tags work. So basically, that's what we have, that's how it works, that's what we use.

Also, as I mentioned in my answer on that question, you can "decouple" the two tags, at least in Tomcat (I don't know if possible in other servlet containers), by using [the following system property](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/systemprops.html#Jasper):

```
-Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.STRICT_GET_PROPERTY=false
```

And now `<jsp:getProperty>` behaves like the EL expression.

---

With that being said, there is this quote I like (attributed to a bunch of people) that says:

> Things are the way they are because they got that way

JSP has been around for a while now. In the beginning, there was no Expression Language. If you wanted to use server tags, you had to use the ones from the `<jsp:` prefix which are defined in the specification and servers need to implement them. It's the bare minimum of "batteries included" to write JSPs nice and clean without throwing a bunch of scriptlets in there and [making a mess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340291/jsp-what-is-wrong-with-scriptlets-and-what-to-use-instead). What was not batteries included you could build on your own with classes and interfaces from the [tag handler package](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/package-summary.html).

With time people started writing their own tags and tag libraries made their appearance. One of the most popular was [JSTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Standard_Tag_Library), which you will usually find under the `<c:` prefix. These are more powerful and flexible tags than what `<jsp:` offered so people started using these in basically every web application out there. I'm not sure if JSTL introduced the `${}` notation or not, but that language became popular because of JSTL.

So time passed and people figured out that all those `${}` evaluations in JSTL and all that language that almost everybody knew - or bumped into sooner or later - could be evaluated directly by the servlet container and thus obtain a much cleaner content. The JSP specifications were enhanced and now you have EL directly implemented, without needing to use `<jsp:getProperty>`.