# how to pass the array list from servelet to jsp table?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

Hi every one can any help me ...

i want to list all the data from data base and display to jsp table

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

    try {
        Connection con=DataConnection.getconnection();
        PreparedStatement pst;
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from [user]");
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        List<User> ee = new ArrayList<User>();

        while (rs.next()) {
            User e = new User();
            e.setName(rs.getString(1));
            e.setUserName(rs.getString(2));
            e.setPass(rs.getString(3));

            ee.add(e);
        }

        request.getSession().setAttribute("ee", ee);
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/user.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);

    } catch (Throwable theException) {
        System.out.println(theException);
    }
}
```

this my code it contain the array list and passing it trought  request.getSession().setAttribute("ee", ee);

now how to acess this value in jsp and it should display in the from of table
can any give me the sample code for this

Comment: Try In your jsp page :-  List<User> ee = new ArrayList<User>();
ee=(List<User>)request.getAttribute(" ee ");

Comment: It is not possible gaurav, because Sameer has set value in Session not in Request.

Answer (score 0):

Use **JSTL**

I would suggest to set data in **request** instead of **session**.

replace line

```
 request.getSession().setAttribute("ee", ee);
```

with

```
 request.setAttribute("ee", ee);
```

than use code below in your JSP

```
<c:forEach items="${ee}" var="element"> 
  <tr>
    <td>${element.col1}</td>
    <td>${element.col2}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks to all for ur support......................

Answer (score 0):

You can access the array using **${ee}**.

There are serveral ways to iterate using JSTL.

Assuming your User.java contains for example two atributes: name and surname you can access to this information in your JSP with the following code:

```
    <%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

    <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.ee}" var="item">
        ${item.name} - ${item.surname} 
    </c:forEach>
```

You should take into account that you are putting your attribute in session. (that's why you have to use **${sessionScope}**) Make sure if you want to use session or not.

Comment: It is not possible, because Sameer has set value in Session not in Request

Comment: yogesh: wrong, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5387174

Comment: That's what i suggested in my answer. :) and comment was made before Oscar edited his answer.