# EL doesn't recognize variable

Tags: jsp, foreach, el

I declared ArrayList variable above.
However, JSP EL Expression doesn't recognize the variable .
How can I fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heBxX.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access objects in EL expression language ${}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387174/how-to-access-objects-in-el-expression-language)

Comment: .. and please don't add code in images