# Why Jsp is not working for getting attribute and why expression tag and taglib is not working check and give me an ans

Tags: jsp, servlets

Servlet code:

```
            String name = "Raj";
    request.setAttribute("lab", name);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher =                 getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/display.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Jsp code :

```
<% String name = (String)request.getAttribute("lab");
        out.println(name); %>
```

it will print null in the jsp page

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77067438/573032) answer.